# Get updating html elements from website using Java

Tags: java, html, eclipse

I want to get updating html elements from a website by using Java.
For example, the twitch-chat.  I've tried using `InputStream` already, but its not continuously refreshing it.

```
URL url;

try {
    String a="www.google.com";
    url = new URL(a);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                       new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea on how I could get that to work?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get the twitch chat of a Twitch-stream thats running. But requesting the whole site every few seconds wont give me any chat messages, because the chat is empty when site is reloaded.

Comment: No idea how i could get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the Problem - at least for [Twitch](http://www.twitch.tv/).

I used the ["Pircbot"](http://www.jibble.org/pircbot.php)-API and added it to the buildpath in Eclipse.